# Replacement for xdebug_get_headers() function in PHP

Tags: php, phpunit, xdebug, pcov

I have a huge project and tests are taking very long. I want to speed up things by switching from `XDebug` to `PCOV`. I see a giant speed gain, but I have one problem. In a few places in my tests, I use `xdebug_get_headers()` to test headers (obviously). With PCOV this function is not available, so I'm looking for ideas for replacement.

I tried `headers_list()` but it won't work on CLI. How I can make it work? Possibly without doing a huge rewrite.